# Typesetting sequence notation

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I attempted to create a sequence both of the following ways:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$(x_j)\limits_{j=1}^\infty$

$(x_j)_{j=1}^\infty$
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get the vertical spacing of the first with the horizontal spacing of the second?[image]

Comment: Are you after something like `$({\displaystyle\mathop{x_j}^\infty_{j=1}})$`?

Comment: @Werner, no, more to shift the limits to just after the right paren.

Comment: Since the right brace is treated as an operator, try the  `mathtools` command `\mathclap{}` like this: `)\limits_{\mathclap{j=1}}^{\mathclap{\infty}}`. This should get rid of the unwanted horizontal left space.

Comment: @AndreaL. Is there a way to make it so that the limits are just one space after the close paren?

Comment: If you want to create a new space between the limits and the brace, I suggest a manual shift using `\mkern`, as Harish Kumar used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an alternative.  It provides left-alignment of the super/subscripts.

EDIT: In an effort to answer the OP's question, "Is there a way to get it so that the limits are left aligned with the horizontal midpoint of the close paren in automatic fashion?"  The answer is yes.  Here it is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\parskip 1.5ex
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\newcommand\specparen[2]{%
  \def\Krn{\kern1ex}%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\Krn\stackengine{0pt}{\scriptstyle#1}{\scriptstyle#2}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}%
  \stackon[2pt]{\stackunder[2pt]{)}{\makebox[\wd0][l]{\Krn$\scriptstyle#1$}}}%
                                   {\makebox[\wd0][l]{\Krn$\scriptstyle#2$}}%
}
$(x_j\specparen{j=1}{\infty} = y$

$(x_j\specparen{j=1}{j=\infty} = y$
\end{document}
```

Here is with `\Krn` set to 0ex (which truly sets the sub/superscript midpoint to the center of the right paren):

[image]

and here it is with `\Krn` set to 1ex (which does a controllable rightward shift of the sub/superscript):

[image]

Comment: I'm curious. Is there a way to get it so that the limits are left aligned with the horizontal midpoint of the close paren in automatic fashion? Currently, I have to muck about with `mu` or `pt` to make it work.

Comment: @soandos  Please see revision.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thank you. Didn't realized that there was such a mechanism (`em` and `ex`)

Comment: @soandos Nice thing is that em and ex scale with the document fontsize, whereas pt does not.  However, even em and ex do not scale with smaller math styles (`\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`), though provisions can be made for that too (see `\ThisStyle{}` of the `scalerel` package, for example).

Comment: Interesting. Also, do you have any idea why MikTeX cannot seem to find stackengine?

Comment: @soandos  The package is nearly a year old, but if your installation can't find it, it can be downloaded here:  http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine

Answer (score 9):

Like the following?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$(x_j\mkern-10.5mu\mathop{)}\limits_{j=1}^\infty$

$(x_j)\mkern-10.5mu\mathop{\vphantom{)}}\limits_{j=1}^\infty$

$\mathop{(x_j)}\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}$

$(x_j)_{j=1}^\infty$
\end{document}
```

[image]